# ggplot2 putting two plots on one

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have some data of x values called "norm". I want to plot a histogram and then plot the density function of a beta with parameters 3.5 and 3 onto the histogram. The main goal of this is to show that the beta fits the norm data. I also need the scale of the y axis to match for both the density and the histogram. I got a plot at one point but the density function was very low because the histogram counted so the y axis went to 30 in my case and obviously the density line was <1.

Here is my code:

```
x <- seq(0,1, len = 115)
db_trial = dbeta(x, 3.5, 3.0)

ggplot(data = norm)+
  geom_line(aes(x,db_trial), col = "red", stat = "density")+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ...density...), bins = 10, alpha = .2, fill = 
  "green", col = "red")
```

Here is my data set norm which is just the presidents data set in R but divided by 100.

```
# dput(norm)

structure(list(approval_rate = c(0.87, 0.82, 0.75, 0.63, 0.5, 
0.43, 0.32, 0.35, 0.6, 0.54, 0.55, 0.36, 0.39, 0.69, 0.57, 0.57, 
0.51, 0.45, 0.37, 0.46, 0.39, 0.36, 0.24, 0.32, 0.23, 0.25, 0.32, 
0.32, 0.59, 0.74, 0.75, 0.6, 0.71, 0.61, 0.71, 0.57, 0.71, 0.68, 
0.79, 0.73, 0.76, 0.71, 0.67, 0.75, 0.79, 0.62, 0.63, 0.57, 0.6, 
0.49, 0.48, 0.52, 0.57, 0.62, 0.61, 0.66, 0.71, 0.62, 0.61, 0.57, 
0.72, 0.83, 0.71, 0.78, 0.79, 0.71, 0.62, 0.74, 0.76, 0.64, 0.62, 
0.57, 0.8, 0.73, 0.69, 0.69, 0.71, 0.64, 0.69, 0.62, 0.63, 0.46, 
0.56, 0.44, 0.44, 0.52, 0.38, 0.46, 0.36, 0.49, 0.35, 0.44, 0.59, 
0.65, 0.65, 0.56, 0.66, 0.53, 0.61, 0.52, 0.51, 0.48, 0.54, 0.49, 
0.49, 0.61, 0.68, 0.44, 0.4, 0.27, 0.28, 0.25, 0.24, 0.24, 0.01
)), .Names = "approval_rate", row.names = c(NA, -115L), class = "data.frame")
```

This returns an error "Stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x". What am I doing wrong. I am a novice with ggplot2.

Comment: Can you post your main data set with `dput(norm)`?

Comment: I updated my post with data and a description of where I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually better to use `stat_function` for this type of thing. Note that I'm technically using an anonymous function that wraps `dbeta`, so you can adjust the height of the curve via multiplication.

```
g <- ggplot(data = norm, aes(x = approval_rate))+
  geom_histogram() +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) dbeta(x, shape1 = 3.5, shape2 = 3.0) * 5, color = 'red')
print(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can I adjust the binwidth as I did before? It looks a lot nicer when it has larger bins like .1

Comment: Yes: `geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1)`

Comment: The only concern I have now is the density function cannot be greater than 1. This is misrepresenting the density function. I read that you can change the histogram to produce frequency rather than count. Do you know about this?

Comment: The beta distribution is only defined for values (probabilities) between 0 and 1.

Comment: Im sorry, i got mixed up in my head. This was a good solution and i received an A on the project. Thank you for your help @jdobres